# java for web application - can it handle the load?

Tags: java, web, load

I'm about to write a web application that's supposed to handle dozens of reads/writes per second. I'm was thinking of doing it in Java instead of PHP, just for doing something different. My question is, how heavy is java on the server? Will it be able to handle the load without consuming more than 512MB of ram (vps)? I've heard about memory allocation in Java and that it consumes much but I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: Its not an entirely answerable question. Yes it is possible, but if you throw an inefficient software stack at it or write your code poorly then it is going to fail. That is true for any technology.

Answer (score 1):

Java is used for many web applications, including high load web applications. Java, and its associated frameworks for web applications, have adequate performance.